# Merge duplicated rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Need to merge contents in the second row if find duplicates in the second row.

Input:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['A001','A002','A002','A003'],
                 'B':['ROW1','ROW2','ROW3','ROW4']})
```

Expected Output:

```
    A   B
0   A001    ROW1
1   A002    ROW2ROW3
2   A003    ROW4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` "A", `agg` using `''.join` to join the strings:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(''.join)
```

output:

```
      A         B
0  A001      ROW1
1  A002  ROW2ROW3
2  A003      ROW4
```